# Describe an array containing an object (stdClass) with @phpstan-return in PHP DocBlock? - PHPStan

Tags: php, arrays, phpdoc, stdclass, phpstan

I have an example function in PHP *(8.2)* that returns an `array`. Inside this `array` there is also an `object`, more precisely `stdClass`.

I use PHPStan as a static analyzer tool. How can I specify this (object shapes) structure syntactically correct to use it in `@phpstan-return` using [PHPStan Array shapes](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#array-shapes) ?

**The example function `getBooks()`:**

```php
function getBook(): array
{
    $author = new stdClass();
    $author->firstName = 'John';
    $author->lastName = 'Doe';

    return [
        'id' => 12345,
        'title' => 'Whoever may help me deserves a big "Thank You!"',
        'authors' => $author,
    ];
}
```

What I already tried and is an invalid syntax:

```php
/**
 * @phpstan-return array{
 *     id: int,
 *     title: string,
 *     authors: object{
 *         firstName: string,
 *         lastName: string,
 *     },
 * }
 */
```

What I definitely already know is, that the `object { .. }` part is the syntactically incorrect one here.

Comment: As of PHPStan v1.10 **object shapes** are **not supported** currently. Also see https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/2923 and https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/6892 and the PR https://github.com/phpstan/phpdoc-parser/pull/141

Comment: I guess the natural question is: if you can describe the shape to a static analyser, why would you not describe that shape to PHP itself, by defining a named class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PHPStan `1.10.12` this is now possible:

https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#object-shapes

So, for your case, that would be written:

```php
/**
 * @return object{
 *     id: int,
 *     title: string,
 *     authors: object{
 *         firstName: string,
 *         lastName: string,
 *     },
 * }
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the associative array architecture with the `array<keyType, valType|valType|...>` pattern:

```php
/** @return array<string, int|stdClass|string> */
function getBook(): array
{ ... }
```

<kbd>**[PHPStan demo](https://phpstan.org/r/f766ff93-5fbd-4117-90b4-7313b2b35c63)**</kbd>

or specify that it is a mixed array:

```php
/** @return array<mixed> */
function getBook(): array
{ ... }
```